# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in portfolio-list.php

Tags: errors, terms, php

I'm having trouble with my WordPress theme.

I'm getting the error below after uploading a featured image into my portfolio item(s):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/maryhtran/public_html/wp-content/themes/Motive/portfolio-list.php on line 150

This is the code that is causing the error found in `portfolio-list.php`:

```
// Get the terms( categories ) for the portfolio item
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_item->ID, 'portfolio_categories' );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
// some code here
}
```

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix this error?

Comment: This problem requires knowledge of how the theme was built. So, you're better off asking it's author than a general purpose site like WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the `foreach()` is fed with an invalid entry, because there is no term returned. To prevent this, wrap your loop inside a conditional:

```
// Get the terms( categories ) for the portfolio item
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_item->ID, 'portfolio_categories' );
if(is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)){
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    // some code here
    }
}
```

Now, the loop will only run only the post has some terms.

Comment: Two additional notes:
1. Please create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you do that.
2. As a quick work-around for this bug (which you should report to the theme author so he can fix it) make sure that each post has at least one category assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your theme. Contact the theme support people. That is the proper place to ask theme-related questions.

(But, the error looks like the `get_the_terms()` function is not returning an array, so the `foreach` won't work.)

That has to be fixed by the theme author.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a little hard to predict but here are some options you could try:

1. Try echoing out the post id to see it it is actually populating.
2. Check if "portfolio_categories" is the exact name to your taxonomy. You can hover over the link in admin panel and look for "taxonomy=[some_name]" in the URL.

Check these things and see what you can find.